# Is there a way to run powershell code in python

Tags: python, powershell

Is there a way to run powershell code in python? I've been searching around and all I'm finding is how to run a separate PS script file in python, but nothing about running PS code.

Example: Let's say I want to run this command from inside a Python script\program...

```
Start-Process -filepath "Path\Filename.exe" -wait
```

I understand in that example I could just run the file using Python. I'm looking into writing a Python app, but it would use some powershell code behind the scenes to actually do what it needs to do. In the case for my app idea, it would connect to Office 365 and manipulate users\account info (add, remove, etc) and things you can't do on the 365 admin site. I already have a PS script to do most of this, but I'm looking into a GUI interface and python seems to be the better choice for GUI (so far as what I've seen and played with).

If this isn't possible, or if it's more pain than it's worth I'd appreciate some suggestions. Should I look into C# or something like that? Python seemed easier to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: So the general consensus I'm seeing from the answers below is that it's either not possible, or not practical. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you Want to embed PowerShell script in exe, vc++ is probably the way to go.

You can use `system` function in `<stdlib>` to run commands in cmd

here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass <your PSScript path>");
    return 0;
}
```

but this code will require you have the `ps1` file on your local box.

---

my suggestion is to run if from the remote. host you `ps1` file on GitHub or gist

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('<url to your script>")');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 1):

Just start powershell.exe (untested)

```
os.system("powershell.exe", "script.ps1")
```

You may need an additional parameters to specify path and execution policy.

Comment: Thanks, Esben. However, it looks like that's just calling a separate powershell script. I'm looking to embed the powershell code inside the python script itself which I'd then convert\package into an EXE file making it a lot easier to share.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just write a powershell script file and then call it? (untested)

```
f = open("script.ps1")
f.write(...) #Script you want to run
f.close()
os.system("powershell.exe", "script.ps1")
```

Comment: Yes, but not for I want to do. Thanks.